# Homotopy theory of non-test categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with pullbacks, and consider the functor $i_\mathcal{C}: \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$, $X \mapsto \mathcal{C}/X$. We can equip $\mathcal{C}$ with a class $\mathcal{W}$ of "weak equivalences" by setting $\mathcal{W} = i_\mathcal{C}^{-1}(\mathcal{W}_\mathsf{Cat})$, where $\mathcal{W}_\mathsf{Cat}$ is the class of functors that induce weak equivalences of nerves. Cisinski shows that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a (Grothendieck) topos, then there is a model structure on $\mathcal{C}$ with weak equivalences $\mathcal{W}$ and cofibrations the monomorphisms. Moreover, Cisinski proves a conjecture of Grothendieck, saying that if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of presheaves on a so-called [test category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/test+category), then the homotopy theory of $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{W})$ is equivalent to the homotopy theory of spaces (for example, the model structure is Quillen equivalent to the usual Quillen model structure on simplicial sets).

But what about Grothendieck toposes which are not presheaf categories on test categories? Cisinski's theory gives us a way to associate a homotopy theory to any Grothendieck topos -- what is that homotopy theory?

I'm basically wondering what is known about the homotopy theory of $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W})$. For example, is it related to the etale homotopy type of $\mathcal{C}$? I might guess that it is some sort of slice category over the etale homotopy type.

Comment: Since $C/X$ always has a final object $X \xrightarrow{1} X$, its nerve is contractible. As described, all objects of $C$ will be weakly equivalent. In the definition of a test category one considers presheaves $[C^{op}, Set]$ and overcategories only of the form $C/X$. I assume you're asking what is the homotopy theory of presheaves on $C$ for a general $C$ via the above construction.

Comment: Agh, of course! For now, let's just assume we're talking about presheaf toposes so we have a canoncial site $C$ for the topos $\mathcal{C} = [C^\mathrm{op},\mathsf{Set}]$, and we can take $i_\mathcal{C}(X) = C/X$ as you say. I think Cisinski has some work that's not restricted just to presheaf toposes, though. I will track it down and edit my question accordingly.

Comment: If I'd take a guess I'd say that for moderately good $C$'s the corresponding theory would be the subcategory of spaces generated by spaces of the form $P\otimes N(C/\cdot)$, where $N$ is the nerve, $P: [C^{op}, Set]$, $\otimes$ means the homotopy coend (which can be described just as a homotopy colimit over a different category) and $C/\cdot$ is the covariant functor of overcategory. The problems is that 1). I see no reason why all maps between spaces would be generated this way, in fact often they won't; 2). objects of $C$ may have equivalent nerves, but not connected by a chain of equivs.

Comment: In fact, if you just consider presheaves of sets on a discrete category $C$, then the described construction is tautological: you get again $[C^{op}, Set]$, which is purely discrete and 1-categorical. I'm not sure how one can formulate a theorem for a general $C$ that would nicely interpolate between a purely homotopy-theoretic and a purely discrete world.

Comment: What is the étale homotopy type of a topos? Is this the Artin-Mazur pro-homotopy type?

Comment: @ArturJackson That's what I mean -- or perhaps a refinement along the lines of Bousfield-Friedlander. My terminology is probably nonstandard. I'm pretty sure this is the same as the [shape](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+of+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos) of the topos regarded as a locally discrete $\infty$-topos.

Comment: What Cisinski proves in his book _Les préfaisceaux comme modèles des types d'homotopie_ is that the category of presheaves of a small category $A$ is equipped with a model structure such that cofibrations are monomorphisms and the weak equivalences are the morphisms you describe if and only if $A$ is local test (and it always model homotopy types). It is not true in general: think about the category of semi-simplices $\Delta'$, _i.e._ the subcategory of simplices where you consider only non-decreasing maps. The category of semi-simplicial presheaves do not allow a model structure of that kind.

Comment: I think that is *essentially* the shape. I think I learned this from a note by Marc Hoyois :). "A note on étale homotopy." I think this was subsumed into Higher Galois Theory? @MarcHoyois ?

One needs to be a bit careful though, I believe, when tracing through the classical constructions of Artin-Mazur, Friedlander, etc. Artin-Mazur first produced pro-homotopy types. Then Friedlander "rigidified" this to give a (pro-)topological type. Fancier constructions upgrade this construction to an $\infty$-functor. And the former is the so called `shape.'

Comment: @TimCapion: I'm quite interested in this question for a number of reasons. Lars Hesselholt asked me once if (very) special $\Gamma$-spaces/sets can be seen as the sheaves on $\Gamma = \mathbf{Fin}^{op}$ for some topology.

I don't think this $\Gamma$ is a test category. (Although, I haven't checked.) I'm curious to know what Cisinski's associated homotopy theory looks like! 

May or may not be useful: Some people think that the inclusion of $\Gamma$-sets into $\Gamma$-spaces is essentially surjective on homotopy classes.

Comment: Cisinski gives a model structure on presheaves on $\Gamma^\mathrm{op} = \mathsf{FinSet}$ which is Quillen-equivalent to spaces... only certain monomorphisms are cofibrations; the construction uses his notion of generalized Reedy category rather than his general presheaf machinery. But that's on the opposite category, and on $\Gamma$ itself of course one is going for connective spectra...

Comment: Andrea's comments above are not completely accurate: in the case of a local test category, we get a model structure which models spaces over the nerve of $\mathcal C$. For information, the nlab page on test categories now contains a summary of the main results in English. As for presheaves on finite sets, we also model structures with all monomorphisms as cofibrations, but the version with fewer cofibrations is nicer because we have explicit generators for trivial cofibrations.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example.

Consider the truncated category $\Delta_{\le n+1}$. Then presheaves on this with the model structure presents $n$-types.

EDIT:
Andrea points out that the relevant Quillen equivalences+proofs can be found in **Corollary 9.2.7** of Cisinski's book *Les préfaisceaux comme modèles des types d'homotopie*.

Comment: I'm curious if this fits with Anton's comments!

Comment: I don't think I believe this. In general there is a conservative functor (of ∞-categories) $\mathcal C[\mathcal W^{-1}] \to Spaces$ whose image consists of all spaces that are homotopy colimits of $C^{op}$-diagrams of sets. When $C=\Delta_{\leq n}$, these are the spaces of homotopy dimension $\leq n$, and it seems unlikely that there is a conservative functor from $n$-types to spaces of homotopy dimension $\leq n$. What is your reasoning?

Comment: It is instead $\Delta_{\leqslant n+1}$. Indeed, both the pairs $(i^*, i_*)$ and $(i_!, i^*)$ are Quillen equivalences for the model structures of $n$-equivalences, where here $i\colon \Delta_{\leqslant n+1} \to \Delta$ is the canonical embedding. This is proven, for instance, in Corollary 9.2.7 of Cisinski's book _Les préfaisceaux comme modèles des types d'homotopie_ .

Comment: I should add that the class of functors you pullback to presheaves categories in this case is _not_ the class of Thomason weak equivalences described in the OP, but instead a further (left Boudfield) localisation.

Comment: Andrea, am I off by one here?

Comment: This is interesting, but I'm not sure how enlightening it is. As Andreas points out, in order to get this result, you need to change the basic localizer on $\mathsf{Cat}$ you're using. In fact, you need to change it to the localizer $\mathcal{W}_n$ which presents $n$-types on $\mathsf{Cat}$. With this localizer, I presume that the induced Cisinski model structure for the test category $\Delta$ also presents $n$-types, so it's not surprising that the model structure for the local test category $\Delta_{\leq n+1}$ does too.

Comment: @TimCampion, I agree that this is not so enlightening. I think one should find better examples to get a better feel for the issue.